# Why does my v-speed-dial not overlap other components on my Vue page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have got a page where there are several components, in one component I have a `<v-speed-dial>` with a fab button. When I open the speed dial it is placed under the component that's below it.

Here a picture so you can imagine what I am talking about.
[image: Speed Dial Placement]

Here is the code:

```
<template>
<v-card outlined>

    <v-card-title>Selection</v-card-title>

    <v-toolbar height="80" elevation="0">
        <v-speed-dial class="mb-5" direction="bottom">

            <template v-slot:activator>
                <v-btn text fab>
                    <v-icon :color="myIcon.color" x-large>{{ myIcon.name }}</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </template>

            <v-btn fab small color="green">
                <v-icon color="white" x-large @click="changeStatusToUp()">mdi-chevron-up</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn fab small color="grey">
                <v-icon color="white" x-large @click="changeStatusToMid()">mdi-unfold-less-vertical</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn fab small color="red">
                <v-icon color="white" x-large @click="changeStatusToDown()">mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

        </v-speed-dial>

    </v-toolbar>

</v-card>
```

And here the JavaScript code, if it matters:

```
<script>

export default {
    name: "Selection",
    data() {
        return {

            myIcon: {
                name: 'mdi-unfold-less-vertical',
                color: 'grey'
            },
            colors: {
                red: 'red',
                green: 'green',
                grey: 'grey'
            }
        }
    },
    props: {},
    computed: {},
    methods: {

        changeStatusToUp() {
            this.myIcon.name = 'mdi-chevron-up'
            this.myIcon.color = 'green'
        }
        ,
        changeStatusToDown() {
            this.myIcon.name = 'mdi-chevron-down'
            this.myIcon.color = 'red'
        }
        ,
        changeStatusToMid() {
            this.myIcon.name = 'mdi-unfold-less-vertical'
            this.myIcon.color = 'grey'
        }
    }
};
```

Everything works as intended, if I put choose a different direction for the `<v-speed-dial>` to open, it shows fine, it's just hidden behind the component beneath it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your speed dial is inside a `v-toolbar`.

The toolbar component is used for rendering a navigation header generally at the top of the app.

Speed dials are floating buttons generally used at the bottom of the app.

If you remove the `v-toolbar`, your problem should get fixed.

**EDIT:** The vuetify docs [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/floating-action-buttons), show 2 different examples:

- One where `v-btn` is used inside `v-toolbar`
- The other example is using `v-speed-dial`

I think you ended up combining the two. Please go through the examples given in the docs and use the correct HTML based on your requirement

Comment: Thank you for your answer, simply removing the v-toolbar did not do the trick though. Every component on this side is inside a v-card, do you think that could be the problem?